# Can you create URLs for files in sphinx regardless of where they are saved?

Tags: url, uri, python-sphinx, urn

Can you change the location of 'rst' files in sphinx without changing their URIs? I'm working on a documentation where we want to move some files to different folders, without changing the URIs: 
For Example: If you create a sphinx project with `$ sphinx-quickstart` and add some files and folders:
`index.rst`
`/tutorials/howToFoo.rst`
`/scripts/`
With the toctree in in `index.rst` looking like that:

```
.. toctree::
:maxdepth: 1
:caption: Processing:
:glob:

scripts/*
tutorials/*
```

Then after building the project with `make html`, you have a link in your browser as seen here: [tutorials/howToFoo.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZUzq.png)
If you want to save the the file in a different folder:
`index.rst`
`/tutorials/`
`/scripts/howToFoo.rst`
Then the URL of your file `howToFoo.rst` changes depending on where it is saved:
[scripts/howToFoo.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR1YF.png). 
This is a problem because I don't want links to tutorials or scripts to break.
As the project aims to include many people, it will be very probable that there will be changes in the file structure in the future.

Now my question: Can you create a setup where you can move the files without having to write redirects to their new location, every time you move them?

For Cross Referencing inside of Sphinx this is solved for example with targets, explained here: 
https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/cross-referencing-with-sphinx.html#automatically-label-sections 
But this doesn't help me because the link in the browser still stays the same.
What I want is a link `SomeNeverchangingLinkFor_howToFoo.html` regardless of where the file `howToFoo.rst` is saved.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-reredirects/ You should be able to utilize an extension for that.

Comment: But can you use that extension in a way, that it automatically redirects you to the new URL, without you having to write a redirect?

Comment: But as of now, that may be indeed the best solution.